# How to Sanitize a Property in an Angular 2 Model Class

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, model

I have a model class that has thumbnailUrl as a property, which contains a URL of an image on another domain and therefore needs to be sanitized before rendering in the component's template. I've created a property thubnailStyleUrl which should return the sanitized style (SafeStyle) to be used in the template as a background-image.

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

**Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustStyle' of undefined.**

Can DomSanitizer be injected into a model's constructor like I am attempting below? If not what other options do I have to sanitize this property before rendering.

Here's my model class...

```
import {DomSanitizer, SafeStyle} from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class RecentOrderModel {

    constructor(dataModel:any, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.orderNum = dataModel.orderNum;
        this.poNum = dataModel.poNum;
        this.buyerName = dataModel.buyerName;
        this.thumbnailUrl = dataModel.thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public get thumbnailStyleUrl() :SafeStyle {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url('+this.thumbnailUrl+')');
    }

    orderNum:string;
    poNum:string;
    buyerName:string;
    thumbnailUrl:string;


}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version (RC.6)?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have dependency injection if you call this model as

```
new RecentOrderModel();
```

However if you call this from a `service` or a `component` you can do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class RecentOrderFactory {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    public createOrderModel(datamodel: any) : RecentOrderModel {
        return new RecentOrderModel(datamodel, this._sanitizer);
    }

}
```

This factory should be added to your `providers` array.